# How to replace AXIS' "Hi there, this is an AXIS service!" page?

Tags: web-services, axis

When I go to "http://192.168.0.149:8080/axis/services/MyService", I get this page

"Hi there, this is an AXIS service!

*Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...*"

I know this means my web service is working correctly (in fact, I have a java client that calls it just fine). But yesterday I've been asked a simple question, yet I don't know the answer and couldn't find it. **Can we replace that page**, by an actual form let's say? Is there a setting to add to our web.xml file, or perhaps something else?

I know that axis is deployed as a jar file on my server (there's no /axis directory), so this may limit my possibilities...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.

You can subclass AxisServlet and redefine the reportServiceInfo() method (that's the one that prints "Hi there, ...").

```
package com.abcd.ws;

import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyAxisServlet extends org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet {
    protected void reportServiceInfo(
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response,
            java.io.PrintWriter writer, org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService service,
            java.lang.String serviceName) {
        //writer.write("We can print stuff here, or redirect :");
        // The leading slash means we are redirecting using an absolute path
        String redirectPage = response.encodeRedirectURL("/" + serviceName + ".jsp");
        try {
            response.sendRedirect(redirectPage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

You then need to change in your web.xml the mapping on AxisServlet to use that class.